# The importance of the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function

Tags: real-analysis

In my measure theory class, we've spent a good chunk of the last week or so studying the Hardy-Littlewood Maximal function defined for a function $f\in L_{loc}^1 (\mathbb{R}^d)$ as $$ Mf(x) = sup_{x\in B} \frac{1}{m(B)} \int_B |f(y)| dy $$

We've shown that in general, $Mf\notin L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, unless $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

My question is, what motivates the study of such a function? Why do we care about $Mf$? And how did somebody (I'm presuming Hardy and/or Littlewood) come up with such a function in the first place?

Comment: There a lot of applications listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function